# how to compare variables in PYOMO?

Tags: python, binary, pyomo

I have a dummy energy dispatch code which I have created just to learn about how to **compare variables** in **PYOMO** and also how to use **Binary variable** in **PYOMO**.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a concrete model
model = ConcreteModel()
idx = 20
np.random.seed(idx)
model.m_index = Set(initialize=list(range(idx)))

model.load_profile = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, np.random.randint(10, 350, idx))))
model.solar_profile = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, np.random.uniform(0, 0.6, idx))))

# Parameters: Generator capacities
model.gen1_cap = Param(initialize=100)
model.gen2_cap = Param(initialize=100)
model.gen3_cap = Param(initialize=100)
model.backup_cap = Param(initialize=300)

# Parameters: Cost of running generators
model.gen1_cost = Param(initialize=10)
model.gen2_cost = Param(initialize=10)
model.gen3_cost = Param(initialize=10)
model.backup_cost = Param(initialize=-3)

# Variable: Energy given out by generators
model.gen1_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.gen2_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.gen3_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.backup_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

model.gen3_status = Var(model.m_index, domain=Binary)


# Objective function: Maximise the total cost
def production_cost(model):
    total_cost = sum(
        model.gen1_use[m] * model.gen1_cost +
        model.gen2_use[m] * model.gen2_cost +
        model.gen3_use[m] * model.gen3_cost * model.gen3_status[m] +
        model.backup_use[m] * model.backup_cost
        for m in model.m_index)

    return total_cost

model.obj = Objective(rule=production_cost, sense=maximize)


def gen3_on_off(model, m):
    if model.solar_profile[m] >= 0.30:  # This condition works fine
    # if model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] <= 0.90 * model.load_profile[m]:  # This condition gives error
        return model.gen3_status[m] == 1
    else:
        return model.gen3_status[m] == 0

model.gen3_on_off = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen3_on_off)

def energy_balance(model, m):
    eq = model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] + model.gen3_use[m] + model.backup_use[m] >= model.load_profile[m]

    return eq

model.energy_balance = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=energy_balance)

def gen1_max(model, m):
    eq = model.gen1_use[m] <= model.gen1_cap

    return eq


model.gen1_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen1_max)

def gen2_max(model, m):
    eq = model.gen2_use[m] <= model.gen2_cap

    return eq


model.gen2_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen2_max)


def gen3_max(model, m):
    eq = model.gen3_use[m] <= model.gen3_cap * model.solar_profile[m]

    return eq


model.gen3_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen3_max)

def backup_max(model, m):
    eq = model.backup_use[m] <= model.backup_cap

    return eq


model.backup_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=backup_max)

def gen2_on_off(model, m):
    eq = model.gen2_use[m] <= model.gen2_cap

    return eq


# model.gen2_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen2_max)


Solver = SolverFactory('gurobi')
Solver.options['LogFile'] = "gurobiLog"
print('\nConnecting to Gurobi Server...')
results = Solver.solve(model)

if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok):
    if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
        print("\n\n***Optimal solution found***")
        print('obj returned:', round(value(model.obj), 2))
    else:
        print("\n\n***No optimal solution found***")
        if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
            print("Infeasible solution")
            exit()
else:
    print("\n\n***Solver terminated abnormally***")
    exit()

load = []
gen1 = []
gen2 = []
gen3 = []
solar_profile = []
backup = []
gen3_status = []

for i in range(20):
    load.append(value(model.load_profile[i]))
    gen1.append(value(model.gen1_use[i]))
    gen2.append(value(model.gen2_use[i]))
    gen3.append(value(model.gen3_use[i]))
    solar_profile.append(value(model.solar_profile[i]))
    backup.append(value(model.backup_use[i]))
    gen3_status.append(value(model.gen3_status[i]))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Load profile': load,
    'Gen 1': gen1,
    'Gen 2': gen2,
    'Gen 3': gen3,
    'Solar profile': solar_profile,
    'Backup': backup,
    'Gen 3 Status': gen3_status

# 'Gen 2 Status': gen2_status,
})
df.to_excel('binary.xlsx')
print(df)
```

Constraint gen3_on_off is the one where I am facing an issue. If you run this program as it is, it will work but when I comment the first **if statement** and uncomment the second **if statement**:

```
if model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] <= 0.90 * model.load_profile[m]:
```

then this gives an error:

```
WARNING: DEPRECATED: Chained inequalities are deprecated. Use the inequality()
    function to express ranged inequality expressions.
WARNING: DEPRECATED: Chained inequalities are deprecated. Use the inequality()
    function to express ranged inequality expressions.
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint gen3_on_off with
    index 0: TypeError: Relational expression used in an unexpected Boolean
    context.

            The inequality expression:
                84.3  <=  gen1_use[0] + gen2_use[0]
            contains non-constant terms (variables) that were evaluated in an
            unexpected Boolean context at
              File
              'C:\Users\nvats\PycharmProjects\microgrid-v1.0\RTC\test.py',
              line 52:
        if model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] >= 0.30 *
        model.load_profile[m]:  # This condition gives error

            Evaluating Pyomo variables in a Boolean context, e.g.
                if expression <= 5:
            is generally invalid.  If you want to obtain the Boolean value of
            the expression based on the current variable values, explicitly
            evaluate the expression using the value() function:
                if value(expression) <= 5:
            or
                if value(expression <= 5):
ERROR: Constructing component 'gen3_on_off' from data=None failed: TypeError:
    Relational expression used in an unexpected Boolean context.

            The inequality expression:
                84.3  <=  gen1_use[0] + gen2_use[0]
            contains non-constant terms (variables) that were evaluated in an
            unexpected Boolean context at
              File
              'C:\Users\nvats\PycharmProjects\microgrid-v1.0\RTC\test.py',
              line 52:
        if model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] >= 0.30 *
        model.load_profile[m]:  # This condition gives error

            Evaluating Pyomo variables in a Boolean context, e.g.
                if expression <= 5:
            is generally invalid.  If you want to obtain the Boolean value of
            the expression based on the current variable values, explicitly
            evaluate the expression using the value() function:
                if value(expression) <= 5:
            or
                if value(expression <= 5):

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there any way I can add this condition to the constraint:

```
if model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] >= 0.90 * model.load_profile[m]:
```

and set the binary variable to 1 or 0 based on True or False?

Comment: it's like if energy coming from gen1 and gen2 is less than 30% of the load ( which is technically not possible, so just to test it we can set it to 80% or 90%)  then only activate gen3

Comment: All right. Got it. Can you check my answer, please? Be careful, I may have changed the logic of your constraint. However the idea is to replace your constraint with 2 others (named BigM constraints). I made a concrete example to illustrate my point. Leave me a message if something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `gen3_on_off` constraint with:

```
# Some constants
eps = 1e-3  # to create a gap for gen3_status constraints
bigm = 1e3  # choose this value high but not so much to avoid numeric instability

# Create 2 BigM constraints
def gen3_on_off1(model, m):
    return model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] >= 0.30 * model.load_profile[m] + eps - bigm * (1 - model.gen3_status[m])

def gen3_on_off2(model, m):
    return model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] <= 0.30 * model.load_profile[m] + bigm * model.gen3_status[m]

model.gen3_on_off1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen3_on_off1)
model.gen3_on_off2 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen3_on_off2)
```

To understand what I did, you can read the following references:

- [How to write if else statement in Linear programming?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2500415)
- [How do I model conditional statements in Gurobi?](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4414392016529-How-do-I-model-conditional-statements-in-Gurobi-)

Now take a concrete example:

Test `gen_status=1`:

```
# 0.30 * load_profile = 84.3
# gen1_use = 40
# gen2_use = 45

(1) 40 + 45 >= 84.3 + 0.001 - 1000 * (1 - gen_status)
(2) 40 + 45 <= 84.3 + 1000 * gen_status

(1) (40 + 45 - 84.3 - 0.001 + 1000) / 1000 >= gen_status
(2) (40 + 45 - 84.3) / 1000 <= gen_status

# 1.000699 >= gen_status >= 0.0007000000000000028, gen_status=1
```

Test `gen_status=0`:

```
# 0.30 * load_profile = 84.3
# gen1_use = 30
# gen2_use = 35

(1) 30 + 35 <= 84.3 + 0.001 - 1000 * (1 - gen_status)
(2) 30 + 35 >= 84.3 + 1000 * gen_status

(1) (30 + 35 - 84.3 - 0.001 + 1000) / 1000 >= gen_status
(2) (30 + 35 - 84.3) / 1000 <= gen_status

# 0.980699 >= gen_status >= -0.019299999999999998, gen_status=0
```

Comment: Hey, I need some further help regarding this type of implementation only. can you please message me if you have time?

Comment: Hey, I didn't get the notification from the chatbox that you created. If you can open the chatbox again then i have to show you something or if you want i can add another question here

Comment: @Vesper. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256532/room-for-vesper-and-corralien