# How to use binary variable in another constraint in PYOMO?

Tags: python, pyomo, gurobi

I have created an RTC energy dispatch model using PYOMO. There is a demand profile and to serve this demand profile we have three main components: **Solar, Wind, and Battery** just so that the model won't give infeasible errors in case there is not enough energy supply from the three main sources I have added one backup generator called **Lost_Load**
I have added one binary variable called **insufficient_dispatch** which will be **1** if  **lost_load >= 10% of demand profile** else **0**. Here is the inputs that I am using:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *




profiles = pd.read_excel('profiles.xlsx', sheet_name='15min', usecols='B:D')
solar_profile = profiles.iloc[:, 0].values
wind_profile = profiles.iloc[:, 1].values
load_profile = profiles.iloc[:, 2].values


interval_freq = 60
solar_capacity = 120
wind_capacity = 170
power = 90
energy = 360

model = ConcreteModel()

model.m_index = Set(initialize=list(range(len(load_profile))))
# model.total_instance = Param(initialize=35010000)



model.chargeEff = Param(initialize=0.92)
model.dchargeEff = Param(initialize=0.92)
model.storage_power = Param(initialize=power)
model.storage_energy = Param(initialize=energy)

#variable
# model.grid = Var(model.m_index, domain=Reals)
model.grid = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.p_max = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)

# storage
#variable
model.e_in = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.e_out = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.soc = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.ein_eout_lmt = Var(model.m_index, domain=Binary)

#  Solar variable

solar_ac = np.minimum(solar_profile * solar_capacity * (interval_freq / 60), solar_capacity * (interval_freq / 60))
model.solar_cap = Param(initialize=solar_capacity)
model.solar_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

#  Wind variables

wind_ac = np.minimum(wind_profile * wind_capacity * (interval_freq / 60), wind_capacity * (interval_freq / 60))
model.wind_cap = Param(initialize=wind_capacity)
model.wind_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

# Solar profile
model.solar_avl = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, solar_ac)))

# Wind profile
model.wind_avl = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, wind_ac)))

# Load profile
model.load_profile = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, load_profile * interval_freq / 60.0)))

model.lost_load = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

# Auxiliary binary variable for the condition
model.insufficient_dispatch = Var(model.m_index, domain=Binary)


# Objective function
def revenue(model):
    total_revenue = sum(
        model.grid[m] * 100 +
        model.lost_load[m] * -1000000000 #* model.insufficient_dispatch[m]
        for m in model.m_index)

    return total_revenue


model.obj = Objective(rule=revenue, sense=maximize)


eps = 1e-3  # to create a gap for gen3_status constraints
bigm = 1e3  # choose this value high but not so much to avoid numeric instability

# Create 2 BigM constraints
def gen3_on_off1(model, m):
    return model.lost_load[m] >= 0.1 * model.load_profile[m] + eps - bigm * (1 - model.insufficient_dispatch[m])

def gen3_on_off2(model, m):
    return model.lost_load[m] <= 0.1 * model.load_profile[m] + bigm * model.insufficient_dispatch[m]

model.gen3_on_off1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen3_on_off1)
model.gen3_on_off2 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen3_on_off2)


def energy_balance(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] <= model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m] + model.lost_load[m]


model.energy_balance = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=energy_balance)


def grid_limit(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] >= model.load_profile[m]

model.grid_limit = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=grid_limit)


def max_solar_gen(model, m):
    eq = model.solar_use[m] <= model.solar_avl[m] * 1
    return eq


model.max_solar_gen = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_solar_gen)


def min_solar_gen(model, m):
    eq = model.solar_use[m] >= model.solar_avl[m] * 0.6
    return eq


# model.min_solar_gen = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=min_solar_gen)


def max_wind_gen(model, m):
    eq = model.wind_use[m] <= model.wind_avl[m] * 1
    return eq


model.max_wind_gen = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_wind_gen)


def min_wind_gen(model, m):
    eq = model.wind_use[m] >= model.wind_avl[m] * 0.3
    return eq


# model.min_wind_gen = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=min_wind_gen)


# Charging and discharging controller
def ein_limit1(model, m):
    eq = model.e_in[m] + (1 - model.ein_eout_lmt[m]) * 1000000 >= 0

    return eq

model.ein_limit1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=ein_limit1)


def eout_limit1(model, m):
    eq = model.e_out[m] + (1 - model.ein_eout_lmt[m]) * -1000000 <= 0
    return eq

model.eout_limit1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=eout_limit1)


def ein_limit2(model, m):
    eq = model.e_out[m] + (model.ein_eout_lmt[m]) * 1000000 >= 0
    return eq

model.ein_limit2 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=ein_limit2)


def eout_limit2(model, m):
    eq = model.e_in[m] + (model.ein_eout_lmt[m]) * -1000000 <= 0
    return eq

model.eout_limit2 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=eout_limit2)


#max charging
def max_charge(model, m):
    return model.e_in[m] <= model.storage_power*interval_freq/60

model.max_charge = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_charge)


# max discharging
def max_discharge(model, m):
    return model.e_out[m] <= model.storage_power*interval_freq/60

model.max_max_discharge = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_discharge)


def soc_update(model, m):
    if m == 0:
        eq = model.soc[m] == \
             (
                     (model.storage_energy * 1) +
                     (model.e_in[m] * model.chargeEff) -
                     (model.e_out[m] / model.dchargeEff) #* model.insufficient_dispatch[m]
             )
    else:
        eq = model.soc[m] == \
             (
                     model.soc[m - 1] +
                     (model.e_in[m] * model.chargeEff) -
                     (model.e_out[m] / model.dchargeEff) #* model.insufficient_dispatch[m]
             )

    return eq


model.soc_update = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=soc_update)


def soc_min(model, m):
    eq = model.soc[m] >= model.storage_energy * 0.2

    return eq


model.soc_min = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=soc_min)


def soc_max(model, m):
    eq = model.soc[m] <= model.storage_energy * 1

    return eq


model.soc_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=soc_max)

def throughput_limit(model):
    energy_sum = sum(model.e_out[idx] for idx in model.m_index)
    return energy_sum <= model.storage_energy*365


# model.throughput_limit = Constraint(rule=throughput_limit)


Solver = SolverFactory('gurobi')
Solver.options['LogFile'] = "gurobiLog"
Solver.options['MIPGap'] = 0.50
print('\nConnecting to Gurobi Server...')
results = Solver.solve(model)

if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok):
    if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
        print("\n\n***Optimal solution found***")
        print('obj returned:', round(value(model.obj), 2))
    else:
        print("\n\n***No optimal solution found***")
        if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
            print("Infeasible solution")
            exit()
else:
    print("\n\n***Solver terminated abnormally***")
    exit()

grid_use = []
solar = []
wind = []
e_in = []
e_out=[]
soc = []
lost_load = []
insufficient_dispatch = []
load = []

for i in range(len(load_profile)):
    grid_use.append(value(model.grid[i]))
    solar.append(value(model.solar_use[i]))
    wind.append(value(model.wind_use[i]))
    lost_load.append(value(model.lost_load[i]))
    e_in.append(value(model.e_in[i]))
    e_out.append(value(model.e_out[i]))
    soc.append(value(model.soc[i]))
    load.append(value(model.load_profile[i]))
    insufficient_dispatch.append(value(model.insufficient_dispatch[i]))

df_out = pd.DataFrame()

df_out["Grid"] = grid_use
df_out["Potential Solar"] = solar_ac
df_out["Potential Wind"] = wind_ac
df_out["Actual Solar"] = solar
df_out["Actual Wind"] = wind
# df_out["Solar Curtailment"] = solar_ac - np.array(solar)
# df_out["Wind Curtailment"] = wind_ac - np.array(wind)
df_out["Charge"] = e_in
df_out["Discharge"] = e_out
df_out["soc"] = soc
df_out["Lost Load"] = lost_load
df_out["Load profile"] = load
df_out["Dispatch"] = df_out["Grid"] - df_out["Lost Load"]
df_out["Insufficient Supply"] = insufficient_dispatch

summary = {
    'Grid': [df_out['Grid'].sum()/1000],
    'Wind': [df_out['Actual Wind'].sum()/1000],
    'Solar': [df_out['Actual Solar'].sum()/1000],
    'Storage Discharge': [df_out['Discharge'].sum()/1000],
    'Storage Charge': [df_out['Charge'].sum()/1000],
    'Shortfall': [df_out['Lost Load'].sum()/1000],
    # 'Solar Curtailment': [df_out['Solar Curtailment'].sum()/1000],
    # 'Wind Curtailment': [df_out['Wind Curtailment'].sum()/1000],
}


summaryDF = pd.DataFrame(summary)

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d_%H-%M')

with pd.ExcelWriter('output solar '+str(solar_capacity)+'MW wind '+str(wind_capacity)+'MW ESS '+str(power)+'MW and '+str(energy)+'MWh '+str(timestamp)+'.xlsx') as writer:
    df_out.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='dispatch')
    summaryDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary', index=False)
```

I want to use this binary variable **insufficient_dispatch** with another constraint **energy_balance** ( which is already there in the code ) :

```
def energy_balance(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] <= model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m] + model.lost_load[m]
```

it should be like:

```
if model.insufficient_dispatch[m] == 0:
    return model.grid[m] <= model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m] + model.lost_load[m]
else:
    return model.grid[m] * 0.9 <= model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m] + model.lost_load[m]
```

But this won't work, can someone please help?
This is the graphical representation of one of the months:
[image]

how i want is something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are only interested in the left hand side of your inequality, you want `1 * grid` when `insufficient_dispatch == 0` or `0.9 * grid` otherwise.

```
if i == 0:
  1.0 * x <= F
else:
  0.9 * x <= F
```

is equivalent to:

```
(1 - w) + w * 0.9
```

so:

```
w=0, (1 - 0) + 0 * 0.9 gives 1.0
w=1, (1 - 1) + 1 * 0.9 gives 0.9
```

You can rewrite your constraint like:

```
def energy_balance(model, m):
    lhs = ((1 - model.insufficient_dispatch[m]) + model.insufficient_dispatch[m] * 0.9) * model.grid[m]
    return lhs <= model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m] + model.lost_load[m]
```

**Edit**

To keep your model linear, create 2 constraints (same explanation than [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77766255/15239951) of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77765298/15239951)):

```
bigm = 1e3

# When i=0
def energy_balance1(model, m):
   return model.grid[m] <= model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m] + model.lost_load[m] + model.insufficient_dispatch[m] * bigm

# When i=1
def energy_balance2(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] * 0.9 <= model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m] + model.lost_load[m] + (1 - model.insufficient_dispatch[m]) * bigm
```

Comment: Hey, this works on a smaller problem where the total instances are let's say 24 or something. But this is not working as expected for bigger problems where the size of the total instances if around 35040 ( whole year ).

Comment: Hey there is one mistake here , I mentioned one thing wrong here. When i=1 then model.grid[m] * 0.9 <= model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m] + (1 - model.insufficient_dispatch[m]) * bigm

Comment: lost load will not be part of it. And this can give us an infeasible solution because without lost load there can be instances where energy cannot be fulfilled. That's why I was asking if I can add this binary variable to the objective function itself?  Because I want the battery to discharge and charge in a way where we can have the minimum number of instances where model dispatch ( without Lost load ) is less than 90% of the load profile. I thought by adding it to the constraint it will help but it won't solve the problem.